# In linux a file is not empty but the size is 0

Tags: shell, file, cgroups

I test whether a file is empty in Shell.

`test -s /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/docker/d4e311735706485e748513bad611070e223cba76fdf4c72a1102d14b653da750/tasks`

It returns false, and I found its size is 0 when I use `ls -lh`, but when I use `cat`, I can get 4071 in this file, this means the file is not empty. I think maybe this file is too small, I create a file in my home directory, and echo 4071 to it, I find its size is not 0. Is the file in /sys/fs/cgroup special?

Comment: doesn't necessarily mean "at the same time" - maybe the file is written to and being truncated successively? Is it a regular file at all, can you show the ls -l output?

Comment: @Stefan Hegny Thanks for your answer, here is the ls -lh output:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 11 15:47 tasks` I think you are right, this file maybe is written to and beingtruncated, this file records the processes of the container, and it is updated all the time.

Comment: @ cheon at least I'm quite sure that it's not a matter of "too small". Greater than zero in computer language means greater than zero and there is no other "too small" layer ...

Comment: @Stefan Hegny Thany you very much.

Comment: Everything in `/sys` or `/proc`, generally speaking, will be special.

Comment: BTW, how is this a question about software development? I'd think it would be better situated at [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 6):

The file that you are dealing with is a special file which is a part of the cgroup file system.

To understand why this happens, let's see what happens when you do `test -e $filename`.

We will be using `strace` command which prints the system calls a command does.

If you do `strace test -e $filename`, you will find this line in the results:

```
stat("$filename", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
```

In this case it returns `st_size = 0` which is the size of the file.

But the questions is what actually happens on the other side, inside the kernel:

When you try to deal with a file, you do a system call which goes to an intermediate layer in the kernel called the virtual file system which in turn calls the part responsible for the information needed. A stat system call will try to get the status out of the inode corresponding with file. The file system can create and manipulate the inode as it wants.

Cgroup is a special file system, when it adds a file (using the `cgroup_add_file` function defined in [kernel/cgroup.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3007098494bec614fb55dee7bc0410bb7db5ad18/kernel/cgroup.c#L3647)) it always passes size 0 to `__kernfs_create_file` so that is why any file inside /sys/fs/cgroups (created by cgroup fs) will always has a zero size regardless of the actual contents of the file.

For the other part, when cat the file. If you do `strace cat $filename`, that is what you will get:

```
open("$filename", O_RDONLY)                     = 3
read(3, "...", 131072)                          = ###
```

The read system call will go through the virtual file system to the kernel file system and using the file operations associated with the file, it will get you the needed data.

Cgroup fs has functions to generate the data in its files. This is how `tasks` file is defined in [kernel/cgroup.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3007098494bec614fb55dee7bc0410bb7db5ad18/kernel/cgroup.c#L4941)

```
{
        .name = "tasks",
        .seq_start = cgroup_pidlist_start,
        .seq_next = cgroup_pidlist_next,
        .seq_stop = cgroup_pidlist_stop,
        .seq_show = cgroup_pidlist_show,
        .private = CGROUP_FILE_TASKS,
        .write = cgroup_tasks_write,
},
```

So seq_start, seq_next, seq_stop and seq_show are the functions responsible for generating the information needed for the file. You can easily go to [kernel/cgroups.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3007098494bec614fb55dee7bc0410bb7db5ad18/kernel/cgroup.c#L4760) and check for what they do.

Please note that if you are trying to know if the cgroup still has tasks, an easier way is to use notify on release.

from [Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3007098494bec614fb55dee7bc0410bb7db5ad18/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt#L282)

> If the notify_on_release flag is enabled (1) in a cgroup, then whenever the last task in the cgroup leaves (exits or attaches to some other cgroup) and the last child cgroup of that cgroup is removed, then the kernel runs the command specified by the contents of the "release_agent" file in that hierarchy's root directory, supplying the pathname (relative to the mount point of the cgroup file system) of the abandoned cgroup.  This enables automatic removal of abandoned cgroups.  The default value of notify_on_release in the root cgroup at system boot is disabled (0).  The default value of other cgroups at creation is the current value of their parents' notify_on_release settings. The default value of a cgroup hierarchy's release_agent path is empty.